# Stored procedure wrong output

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure that returns data on a selected week, as in the *Company*, *Name*, *Expected Work*, and *Work done* between the 19/10/2015 and the 25/10/2015 (per example).

I have just recently added the Expected Work line and for some odd reason the output differs from one week to another, when the value should be the same.

Company1 - Christopher - 35 - 35 | On one week can give the following on another :

Company1 - Christopher - 350 - 35

I have just realized the value isn't correct when there is a value to *Work done*, if there is no work recorded the *Expected Work* has the right value.

Here is the procedure :

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[spGetWeeklyActivityByEmployee]
      @startDate date
    , @endDate date
as
    set datefirst 1 -- Monday

    select 
        Company.Name as [Company]
        , Employee.FirstName + ' ' + Employee.LastName as [Name]        
        , sum(UserActivity.Cost) as [Recorder Time]
        , sum(Employee.ExpectedTime) as [Expected Time] // I have added this line, not sure if it's correct
    from 
        dbo.Employee
    inner join 
        dbo.Company on Company.CompanyId = Employee.CompanyId
    left join 
        dbo.UserActivity on UserActivity.Login = Employee.Login
                         and UserActivity.CalendarDate >= @startDate
                         and UserActivity.CalendarDate <= @endDate
    where 
        (Employee.EntranceDate is null
         or YEAR(Employee.EntranceDate) < YEAR(@startDate)
         or (YEAR(Employee.EntranceDate) = YEAR(@startDate) 
         and DATEPART(WEEK, Employee.EntranceDate) <= DATEPART(WEEK, @startDate)))
        and (Employee.ExitDate is null
             or YEAR(Employee.ExitDate) > YEAR(@endDate)
             or (YEAR(Employee.ExitDate) = YEAR(@endDate) 
             and DATEPART(WEEK, Employee.ExitDate) >= DATEPART(WEEK, @endDate)))
    group by 
        Company.Name, Employee.FirstName + ' ' + Employee.LastName

    return 0
```

Am I missing something? Is the way I retrieve *Expected Time* wrong?

EDIT :

Here is the part in the code where I save the information in an array :

```
// create and open a connection object
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
conn.Open();

// 1.  create a command object identifying
//     the stored procedure
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetWeeklyActivityByEmployee", conn);

// 2. set the command object so it knows
//    to execute a stored procedure
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

// 3. add parameter to command, which
//    will be passed to the stored procedure
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@startDate", wk1));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@endDate", wk2));

// execute the command
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();         

string[] tab_company = new string[31]; // Don't mind the sizes
string[] tab_name = new string[31];
string[] tab_expectedtime = new string[31];
string[] tab_rectime = new string[31];

int counter;

counter = 0;

while (rdr.Read())
{
    tab_company[counter] = rdr["Company"].ToString();
    tab_name[counter] = rdr["Name"].ToString();
    tab_expectedtime[counter] = rdr["Expected Time"].ToString();
    tab_rectime[counter] = rdr["Recorder Time"].ToString();

    counter++;               
}
```

Perhaps the change in value comes from here?

Comment: One quick idea? Does your `@endDate` include a time? If you do not compare with "23:59:59" you would miss all entries of your end date as `and UserActivity.CalendarDate <= @endDate` would have to be smaller or equal to the first second of `endDate`...

Comment: Yes `@endDate` contains a `DateTime` variable, same goes for `@startDate`.

Comment: As you pass in the parameters with the type `date` it cannot contain a time. Please check this and call back if this does not solve your problem...

Comment: `wk1` (and 2) in `cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@startDate", wk1));` has the following format : `4/13/2015 12:00:00 AM`. So that could be causing an issue?

Comment: Try it with one day later (meaning the first second after midnight of the next day...). Be aware of: Your stored procedure accepts two parameters. both have the type `date`. This will never carry a time... either take midnight of the following day and use `<` or you pass in a `datetime` with a given time. This would be the necessary approach if you'd ever have to deal with times in the middle of a day...

Comment: I see, but may I ask if there is a way to replace `sum` for Employee.ExpectedTime? I believe the issue comes from the fact that I use sum when I shouldn't.

Comment: If you take away the sum for Employee.Expected time you'd have to include this in your list of GROUP BY columns. This could have side effects. Just try it and call back...

Comment: This worked perfectly ! Thank you very much. Please add an answer so I can validate it.

Comment: Hi, glad to read, that I could help you. Answer is there.. Thx for your vote and acceptance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take away the `SUM()` from `Employee.ExpectedTime` and add this to your `GROUP BY`